# C# - Parse/Format a .txt file

Tags: c#, parsing, file, format, text-files

So I have some .txt files that have been formatted in a way that I do not like. I want to read the file and reformat it by a click of a button (or 2) in my GUI. Also, I would like to be able resave the file with many options with a click of another button. Also, if it is possible I would like to have the original file be displayed in a rich text box on the left side of my GUI, and once the format button is clicked it will display the new text on the right side of my GUI in a seperate rich text box.

So I currently have a functioning "Open File" button, "Save File" button, and "Clear Text" button. However, I need a "Format Text" button (unless we can combine the open file button and the format text button into just one button!)...

Here is what the file will look like when it comes in.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlSMm.png

And this is what I want it to look like when I click format.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IzKF.png

I also have a GUI that I have made and to open and save the file I have the following code:

```
    private void openFileButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       OpenFileDialog openFile = new OpenFileDialog();
       openFile.DefaultExt = "*.txt";
       openFile.Filter = ".txt Files|*.txt";
       openFile.InitialDirectory = "C:\\";
       openFile.RestoreDirectory = true;

       try
       {
          if(openFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK && openFile.FileName.Length > 0)
          {
          openedTextRichTextBox.LoadFile(openFile.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
          }
          else
             throw new FileNotFoundException();
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
       }
    }

    private void saveFileButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       SaveFileDialog saveFile = new SaveFileDialog();
       saveFile.DefaultExt = "*.txt";
       saveFile.Filter = ".txt Files|*.txt";
       saveFile.InitialDirectory = "C:\\";
       saveFile.RestoreDirectory = true;

       try
       {
          if(saveFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK && saveFile.FileName.Length > 0)
          {
          formattedTextRichTextBox.LoadFile(saveFile.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
          }
          else
             throw new FileNotFoundException();
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
       }
    }
```

Okay so the actual question is:

How do I format the incoming txt file to delete everything except for (not including) the columns labeled "level", "number ref", "component item", "description". This meaning, everything under the "---" until I hit another "---". After I hit another "---" I need to grab the same columns as above. Does this make more sense? The example of how I want it to look is in the second link.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Shouldn't that be 'formattedTextRichTextBox.SaveFile' in the save file event?

Comment: GUI does not relate with the format conversion. Do the format parsing and conversion without the gui in mind.

Comment: Can you please be more specific?  What does 'format the text' mean?  How do you plan to format it?  I'm not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Paolo, the question seems quite a bit more complex than a homework; not that this makes the question any clearer...

Comment: @Phil Gan I believe this is a "Show me the codez" question. @Colton can you show us what you have done so far in parsing the text, or what you are specifically having trouble with in parsing the text? Stack Overflow normally does not like questions that are just "I need to do this, provide the code to do it", This site is more designed for "I need to do this, and I am stuck on this step"

Comment: Honestly the original format is easier to read then your formatted version.  If you have a question how to do something post the code.  The code you did post is trivial generic code.

Comment: Colton, maybe you should look up Perl. Or another text-processing language.

Comment: @Lirik [`homeworks`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/homework) are not about complexity, are about asking someone else to do your job for you.

Comment: It is not a homework question but rather something I would like to keep my documents more organized. The above documents I just made up but have a similar structure to them.

Comment: @All I am not looking for code but rather guidance on what I should do or maybe think about considering. @Scott Chamberlain I have been trying lots of different ideas but nothing seems to be working how I want it to. I've been working with StreamReader but I can't seem to get it what I want it to do exactly. @Paolo MorettiSchool isnt in session either if you would like more evidence haha..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the text through a regular expression that picks out the lines of interest Something along these lines:

```
        foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines("filename"))
        {
            Match m = Regex.Match(line, @"^\d+\s+[\d\w]+\s+\d+\s+.{24}");
            if (m.Success)
            {
                string output = m.Value;
                // do something with output, for example write to a file
            }
        }
```

If you are not familiar with regular expressions, you should look into them, for example here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: Thanks fredw that helps! There is one problem though. Why is it only printing out the last line instead of every line?

Comment: What does your code look like? are you overriding the "output" variable and using it after the loop?

Comment: foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(openFile.FileName))
                {
                   Match theMatch = Regex.Match(line, @"^\d+\s+[\d\w]+\s+\d+\s+.{25}");
                   if (theMatch.Success)
                   {
                      string output = theMatch.Value;
                      formattedTextRichTextBox.Text = output;
                   }
                }

Comment: You are overriding the text box in the loop. Try this: string output = ""; foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(openFile.FileName)) { Match theMatch = Regex.Match(line, @"^\d+\s+[\d\w]+\s+\d+\s+.{25}"); if (theMatch.Success) { output += theMatch.Value + "\n";  } } formattedTextRichTextBox.Text = output;

Comment: Hey thanks for your help! I found out that I wasn't appending the string. instead of "formattedTextRichTextBox.Text = output" I changed it to "formattedTextRichTextBox.Append(output); formattedTextRichTextBox.AppendText("\n");" and it works! Thanks for your help :)